# Show that $\mathcal{S}=\{\cup_{n\in K}(n,n+1]: K \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Clearly $\emptyset \in \mathcal{S}$ by definition. Now, I am struggling to prove that if $E \in \mathcal{S}$ then $\mathbb{R}\setminus E \in \mathcal{S}$. My idea was the following:

$E\in \mathcal{S} \Rightarrow E=\bigcup_{n\in K}(n,n+1]$ for some $K\subset \mathbb{Z}$. This implies that $\mathbb{R}\setminus E=\bigcap_{n\in K}(\mathbb{R}\setminus (n,n+1])$. Not exactly sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

It's just in bijection with the powerset of $\Bbb Z$, sending $K$ to $f(K):=\bigcup_{n \in K} [n,n+1) \in \mathcal{S}$. As $f$ preserves unions and intersections and complements, this is an isomorphism of algebras. It's obvious $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, hence so is $\mathcal{S}$. $\mathcal{S}$ is just the powerset of $\Bbb Z$ with all points of $\Bbb Z$ "swollen" to an interval in a disjoint way, you could say.